# How to add hover transition for links?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a transition effect for my links. I want the `text-decoration`(which is `underlink`) to slowly appear. Ive tried this and it doesnt work:

```
#slink{
    transition-property: text-decoration;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}
#slink:hover{
    background: none;
}
```

What do I need to do for it to work?

Comment: Maybe specify the `text-decoration` in #slink:hover? Because that's the property you applied the transition to, but you're not changing it, so there's nothing to transit.

Comment: In any case the text-decoration property is not animatable AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use border-bottom!

```
a {
  transition: border-bottom 1s ease;
}
a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```